# VECM of higher rank - results interpretation

Tags: vector-error-correction-model

Right now I am making a VECM model of rank 5 and 12 lags. (The rank was suggested by the Johansen test and the number of lags by varsoc step (stata)).

How do I interpret the results? What does the rank suggest?